# Can a bounty be awarded for the same user in the same question multiple times?

Tags: support, bounties

Can a bounty be awarded for the same user in the same question multiple times?

Say a bounty was started and userX was awarded so now next to his question the bounty score appears.

Now, if a bounty is started again on the same question, can the same userX be awarded one more time?

Comment: Yes, it can be.

Comment: Not only can the same user get multiple bounties - they can get them on the same answer.

Answer (score 6):

Sure! from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> **How do I award a bounty?**
>
> A bounty can be awarded 24 hours after the bounty was started. Any
>   answer to the question, **even an existing answer that has already
>   been awarded one or more bounties**, is eligible to be manually
>   awarded the bounty.